# Possible to inject JavaScript into an existing page to alter a D3JS chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If there is a 3rd party web page (not under my control) that uses D3.js to draw charts, is it technically possible to inject JavaScript into that page to modify the chart?  For example let's say a page used an animated [Bubble Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063269) and I wanted to modify it so the bubbles left a trail as they moved, could I inject the necessary JavaScript into that page?

And, if the owner of the site appreciated user's desire to perform such customization, would it be possible for them to include a standard text area into which one could enter the customization script, and it would then be run whenever the user visited the site?  (Obviously the script would have to be persisted into the user profile and retrieved when that individual user returned to the site.)

Comment: If this is possible, wouldn't that be hacking someones site?

Comment: That's what user scripts are for.

Comment: First paragraph: Yes, but only via the address bar. Try to enter `javascript:[your js code]` into the address bar on the 3rd party page and hit the enter key. Script should run on that page. Second paragraph: Yes, it's up the the owner of the website if they want to allow arbitrary user JS code from a text input to be executed. Technically possible.